# how to GET data using HttpWebRequest

Tags: c#, json

I am working getting data using HttpWebRequest and run into stream not readable error using the below code.

```
        JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        string getUrl = "http://url.com";
        var getdata = "";

        HttpWebRequest webrequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(getUrl);
        webrequest.Method = "GET";
        webrequest.ContentType = "application/json";
        webrequest.ContentLength = data.Length;

        using (HttpWebResponse webresponse = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
        using (Stream stream = webresponse.GetResponseStream())
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream)) //stream not readable error
        {
            getdata = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }

        dynamic getjsondata = jss.Deserialize<dynamic>(getdata);
```

Not sure where I am doing it wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't supply `ContentType` or `ContentLength` for an HTTP Get, the server does that in the response.

In your first `using` statement, you're calling a different `request` object.

Try this (no exception handling included):

```
        JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        string getUrl = "http://url.com";
        var getdata = "";

        HttpWebRequest webRequest = WebRequest.CreateHttp(getUrl);
        //webrequest.Method = "GET"; // GET is the default.

        using (var webResponse = webRequest.GetResponse())
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            getdata = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }

        dynamic getjsondata = jss.Deserialize<dynamic>(getdata);
```

You could add an accept header if needed by the endpoint though:

```
webRequest.Accept = "application/json";
```